# java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, exception, service, widget, android-context

In my app I check if the fragment is visible. If yes then the home screen should be updated.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(isVisibleToUser){
        new UpdateNewsWidgetService().startBakingService(getActivity(),newsArrayList);
    }
}
```

However I get an null pointer exception in here

```
new UpdateNewsWidgetService().startBakingService(getActivity(),newsArrayList);
```

The UpdateNewsWidgetService class is

```
public class UpdateNewsWidgetService extends IntentService {

ArrayList<News> newsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


public UpdateNewsWidgetService() {
    super("UpdateNewsWidgetService");
}

public static void startBakingService(Context context, ArrayList<News> news) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateNewsWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra("news_list",news);
    context.startService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent( Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = prefs.getString("news", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>(){}.getType();
        newsArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        handleActionUpdateNewsWidget(newsArrayList);

    }
}

private void handleActionUpdateNewsWidget(ArrayList<News> newsArrayList){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE2");
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE2");
    intent.putExtra("news_list", newsArrayList);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

So basically this line causes the exception.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateNewsWidgetService.class);
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your context is null.
You could also try to use `getContext()` instead of `getActivity()`.